I'm having an issue with the access token I received through the multi-tenant app containing permissions I didn't add
I'm creating an app that uses Entra ID to call Graph API to access resources.
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"  # The tenant ID changes dynamically according to the tenant ID of the app user.

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    token_data = {
        'client_id': client_id, # client id of A's Entra ID App
        'client_secret': client_secret,  # client secret of A's Entra ID App
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    }

The backend function that requests the access token is as above. Since it is an environment where users cannot log in, users request the issuance of the token with client_credentials as grant type. The purpose is to include only application permissions in the access token. I only added Presence.Read.All to the application permissions, and I expect that this access token will not be accessible other than the API that can only be used with Presence.Read.All.
The tenant in which the Entra ID app is registered will be called Company A, and the customer company that will issue the access token through the app will be called Company B.
If you issue a token by putting Company A's tenant id in url, the access token, which is application permission, Presence.Read.All, will be issued without fail.
The problem is that if you put Company B's tenant id in url and issue an access token, you will get an access token with a number of advanced privileges that are not included in Company A's Entra ID app. This is expected to cause serious security concerns.
How do I work this out? How do I not include permissions that I have not added to the permissions of the Entra ID application in the permissions of the access token?
If I can't solve this, I'd like to know how to issue an access token that is only available to User.Read.All and an access token that is only available to Presence.Read.All separately.
My Entra ID App Permissions
[List of roles when issued with tenant A ID]
"roles": [
    "Presence.Read.All"
  ]

[List of roles when issued with tenant B ID]

  "roles": [
    "User.ReadBasic.All",
    "Presence.ReadWrite.All",
    "Presence.Read.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Application.Read.All"
  ],

